# Generating mouse,key...etc events in linux

Tags: c, linux, events

I am in a project where I will need to write a simple driver that accepts input from a USB device and preforms actions on GUI according to the received msg (Like writing a usb mouse driver but with my own protocol).
I am searching the possibility of this and I found software testing automation tools like LDTP that already can generate actions like mouse clicks and keyboard hits .
Are there other APIs to use ? How long it will consume given that my team has good understanding of C language and no experience with Linux ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have basically two options, that I can think of:

- X11: Use the XTest extension (`XTestFakeDeviceKeyEvent`, `XTestFakeRelativeMotionEvent`, etc.)
- Module uinput.

The first one makes use of *fake* input devices (try running `xinput list` in the shell) that are present in most (all?) X servers. Each call to one of the `XTestFake*` function generates an X input message.

The second one is a kernel module that allows a user application to create input devices and send input events. You simply open the `/dev/uinput` device, send a few `ioctl`s to configure it, and then `write` the input events directly.

And, of course, you can write an input kernel driver!

Comment: go for uinput, unless you're in a system having X,  but not uinput (BSD kernels?). it's not more difficult (it may require more typing, but the API is more intuitive, see examples at: http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) and not X-dependent.

Comment: @ribamar I agree that uinpit is easier. But there are (ot used to be) linux distributions that do not enable uinput by default. Also it usually requires root access, and that may be a problem for some projects.

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to do this very same thing on Windows I looked at the source code of the [VNC Server](http://www.realvnc.com/) for ideas, and found everything I needed to know. The Linux version should have what you need, or at least point you in the right direction. On Linux there are two kinds of VNC servers, those that work on virtual displays and those that work on real ones. You want to look at one that works on a real display, like [this one](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/).

Comment: How much time and effort did yo put on that ?

Comment: On my own project or on learning from VNC? Looking at the VNC code was not difficult, just found the part that inserted keyboard/mouse events and what calls they made to do it. My project required controlling an application (on Windows) with a Wiimote, the event part was not hard at all, but I had a lot of trouble getting a reliable way to read the Wiimote via bluetooth!